# Mismatch on data type? I converted all my ints to long?

Tags: java, arrays, long-integer

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ArrayPractice {
public static void main(String[] arg) {
    long input;
    System.out.println("How Many Times will you roll?");
    Random random=new Random();     
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    input=scan.nextLong();
    long freq[]=new long[7];
    for(long i=1;i<input;i++){
        //1+random.nextInt(6)-numbers 1-6
        ++freq[1+random.nextLong(6)];
    }
    System.out.println("Face\tFrequency");
    for(long i=1;i<freq.length;i++){
        System.out.println(i+"\t"+freq[i]);
    }
}
}
```

Why is my program saying that their is a mismatch at `++freq[1+random.nextLong(6)];
and freq[i]`I converted all my values to long. Why should their be a mismatch?

Comment: arrays can only have `int` as their index.  Given the values can only be between 1 and 6 an `int` is already far more than you need. You don't need it to be a `long` value.

Answer (score 7):

The array's indexes are of type `int`, while `1 + random.nextLong()` will be evaluated as `long`, since `random.nextLong()` returns `long`.

Adding a cast should fix the problem:

```
++freq[(int) (1 + random.nextLong())];
```

or alternatively, you could fetch a random `int`:

```
++freq[1 + random.nextInt(6)];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't index an array with a long. Change it to this:

```
for(int i=1;i<input;i++){
    //1+random.nextInt(6)-numbers 1-6
    ++freq[1+random.nextInt(6)];
}
```